# Keras from TF : loss is NaN and Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, neural-network, tf.keras

I tried to find some solutions that should solves my problem but for the moment none of them are working. (like [Tensorflow ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422670/tensorflow-valueerror-failed-to-find-data-adapter-that-can-handle-input))

I'm doing a neural network through Keras (from TF) using a custom dataset with an input shape : `(5000, 1)` and output shape of `(5000, 16)`.
The inputs are the time and the cycle number and the outputs are the state of each of the 16 lamps (either 0 for off or 1 for on). I use Adam as the optimizer and my loss is 'categorical_crossentropy' (maybe I did an error using this one  ... I not sure of it).

So the problem is when I try to train my network I have this error message :

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Falling back from v2 loop because of error: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

But normally both of my input and output are `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

And my loss is `loss: nan`. This is a bit frustrating since I don't know from where my error can come.

If you have any idea of what's wrong ? I can provide my code if it's too confusing.

Thanks you in advance !

EDIT : As asked, here's my code :

```
    import pandas as pd
    import tensorflow as tf
    
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
    
    # Read csv file into a pandas dataframe
    data= pd.read_excel(r'/datasetV07clear16lamps.xlsx') 
    
    #Index by time
    data.sort_values("Time") 
    print(data.isnull().any() )
    
    #split the dataset 
    train=data[0:5000]
    test=data[5000:]
    print(train.shape)
    print(test.shape)
    
    ## split the dataset into train and test dataset
    # create train dataset
    X1_train=train[['Time']]
    X2_train=train[['cycle']]
y_train=train[['L1green','L1orange','L1red','L1blink','L2green','L2orange','L2red','L2blink','L3green','L3orange','L3red','L3blink','L4green','L4orange','L4red','L4blink']]
    
    #create test dataset
    X1_test=test[['Time']]
    X2_test=test[['cycle']] 

y_test=test[['L1green','L1orange','L1red','L1blink','L2green','L2orange','L2red','L2blink','L3green','L3orange','L3red','L3blink','L4green','L4orange','L4red','L4blink']]

    # Define the input
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(2,))
    
    # Define the output
    output_tensor = Dense(16)(input_tensor)
    
    # Create a model
    model = Model(input_tensor, output_tensor)
    
    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    
    # Fit the model
    model.fit(train[['Time','cycle']], train[['L1green','L1orange','L1red','L1blink','L2green','L2orange','L2red','L2blink','L3green','L3orange','L3red','L3blink','L4green','L4orange','L4red','L4blink']], verbose=True, batch_size=16384, epochs=100)
```

Comment: For a better chance of getting help here, I'd advise you to show your code and point out at the line where the error is.

Comment: Keras can't handle a dataframe as input, `df.values` will give you the values in a numpy array that can be used by Keras. Also, you say that you use categorical crossentropy as a loss function, this loss function is useful if only one light can be on at a single time (it predicts which of the lights is on). If multiple lights can be on, use binary crossentropy instead. Also if you're predicting binary values, use `sigmoid` as activation for your final dense layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

First do the feature scaling by using StandardScaler from sklearn.preprocessing (for inputs and outputs). Then instead of doing 1 nn for all the lines, I do one nn for each.

Still I don't know why I had the error message "`Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, <class 'NoneType'>`