# ValueError in TensorFlow 'categorical_crossentropy'

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to make a submission to the [Titanic problem](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/overview) on kaggle, using TensorFlow.

I used `categorical_crossentropy` in loss, and I got a error after using `fit()`. The error says that my target array should be binary matrices, but my target array is a `Survived` column from training data. This column has only 1s and 0s. What's wrong with it?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

train_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
x_data = train_data[['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
       'Parch', 'Fare']]
x_data = pd.get_dummies(x_data)
y_data = train_data[['Survived']]

X = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[7])
Y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'softmax')(X)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(X, Y)
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_data, y_data, epochs=10) # The error occurred in here.
```

And I got this error message:

```
You are passing a target array of shape (891, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape (samples, classes). If your targets are integer classes, you can convert them to the expected format via:

from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_binary = to_categorical(y_int)

Alternatively, you can use the loss function `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead, which does expect integer targets.
```

Comment: The error even tells you what to do to fix it, did you try it? Binary matrices refers to one-hot encoding your labels.

Comment: I've tried it, but when I fixed it and fitted it, my notebook kernel died.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I used `StandardScaler()` from `sklearn` for my input data and solved my problem.

[Keras from TF : loss is NaN and Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, <class 'NoneType'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550779/keras-from-tf-loss-is-nan-and-failed-to-find-data-adapter-that-can-handle-inpu)